Drill-Through Page Not Filtering Correctly on DAX Measures
I'm having trouble getting the correct related data to display in my drill-through. When I hover over the drill-through button on my bar chart, it's showing the entire table instead of filtering to the specific data.
I've added the drill-through field for all the relevant DAX measures, but it's not producing the expected results.
Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated! PBIX File attached
PBIX File
Many Thanks

Drill-through doesn't work with Measures, you will need to base it on a Dimension.
Try the following:

Create a new Calculated Table (or via Power Query):

Age Weeks = 
  DATATABLE(
    "Week label", STRING,
    "Week Ago", INTEGER,
    {
      {"1 Week",  1},
      {"2 Weeks", 2},
      {"3 Weeks", 3},
      {"4 Weeks", 4}
    }
  )


Create a new Measure (same as your measures but dynamic):

Count Age Weeks = 
  var weekAgo = SELECTEDVALUE('Age Weeks'[Week Ago], 1)
  var prevWeekCompleted = TODAY() - WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 2)
  var periodStart = prevWeekCompleted - (7 * weekAgo) - 1
  var periodEnd = prevWeekCompleted - (7 * weekAgo) + 7
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('20092024'),
        '20092024'[Dispatch Date] >= periodStart &&
        '20092024'[Dispatch Date] <= periodEnd
    )


In your Drill-though page:

add 'Age Weeks'[Week ago] as the Drill-though filter.
on your table visual, add the measure [Count Age Weeks] as Visual filter with is greater than 0.


On your main page - update your chart...



X-axis = 'Age Weeks'[Week label], then right-click on it and select Show items with no data.
- Y-axis = [Count Age Weeks]

That should be it, give it a go.
